# How to enable iOS Simulator -> Device -> Screenshot action

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcrun

I know I can take a screenshot with CMD+S, but I think that the Device -> Screenshot task for the iOS Simulator triggers the

```
UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification
```

notification.

However, his "Screenshot" action appears disabled for the simulator:

[image]

Does someone know how to enable it?

MacOs: Catalina 10.15.3,
Xcode: 11.4

Comment: I'm not certain, but after opening a bunch of simulators it seems like it's only available for iOS 13+ simulators. What version of iOS is that simulator running?

Comment: iOS 12.4, let me build on a iOS 13 one.